# Deselecting a UITableViewCell upon cancelling an ActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiactionsheet

Using -didSelectRowAtIndexPath on a UITableViewCell, I fire off a UIActionSheet and the cell becomes selected. How would I target the specific cell to animate it's deselection upon the action sheet being sent a Cancel message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIActionSheetDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActionSheetDelegate) provides the ability to know when your UIActionSheet was and/or will be dismissed. So you would provide your UIActionSheet a delegate which would deselect the table's selection using [deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the method on `UIActionSheetDelegate` is.